# How should a text button with hover state be aligned?

Tags: css, alignment, button

Using Material UI components for demo (*the misalignment is not as huge with Material but might be more visible with other libraries*)
I am aligning the text button (PRIMARY) against a heading (Form)
**Normal state**
See how the text button is placed slightly right compared to the heading?
[image]

**Hover state**
On hover state, the button now appears to be slightly left compared to heading?
[image]

**Question**: How can we have the text button aligned to heading on both hovered and normal states?

A couple of options come to mind.

- keep the padding minimal to make the misalignment negligible
- move content right on hover to accommodate padding from hover (apply transform effect make it look better)

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zll0r

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The normal state image literally has no button. If there was a button shape behind the text, I don't think you'd have a problem.

Comment: I'd say it's completely fine as it is. If it started bothering me, I'd perhaps try adding `border-left` to the parent element. Maybe it could disappear on hover or you could add some extra white space between the vertical line and the first button. Color could be low opacity gray. Another thing you could do is add a very low opacity gray border or background to each button.

Comment: I'd use a border for the non-hovered state.